# How to convert ogv video file into Mp4 video format using Java

Tags: java, video, ffmpeg

I need to convert OGV VIDEO Format into MP4 VIDEO Format.

- I use this below Java code to convert MP4 VIDEO Format to OGV VIDEO Format it is working fine.
- For MP4 Format I use  audio.setCodec(" AudioAttributes.DIRECT_STREAM_COPY") and video.setCodec("VideoAttributes.DIRECT_STREAM_COPY ").
- But If I use this same code  by change audio.setCodec(" libvorbis") and video.setCodec("mpeg4 ") it is not getting converted from Ogv to Mp4 Format. And also I try some codec in my sample program.
- I am not able convert from Ogv to Mp4 Format.

```
public class VideoConvert {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    File source = new File("D:\\readxml\\videoConvertorProject\\MP4toOGV\\mp4\\Sample1.ogv");
    File target = new File("D:\\readxml\\videoConvertorProject\\MP4toOGV\\ogv\\Sample2.mp4");
    AudioAttributes audio = new AudioAttributes();
    //audio.setCodec("libvorbis");
    audio.setCodec("libfaac");
    //audio.setCodec("libmp3lame");
    //audio.setCodec(AudioAttributes.DIRECT_STREAM_COPY);
    audio.setBitRate(new Integer(128000));
    audio.setSamplingRate(new Integer(44100));
    audio.setChannels(new Integer(2));
    VideoAttributes video = new VideoAttributes();
    video.setBitRate(new Integer(160000));
    video.setFrameRate(new Integer(15));
    //video.setSize(new VideoSize(176, 144));
    //video.setCodec("libtheora");
    video.setCodec("mpeg4");
    //video.setCodec(VideoAttributes.DIRECT_STREAM_COPY);
    EncodingAttributes attrs = new EncodingAttributes();
    attrs.setFormat("mp4");
    attrs.setAudioAttributes(audio);
    attrs.setVideoAttributes(video);
    Encoder encoder = new Encoder();
    try {
        encoder.encode(source, target, attrs);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InputFormatException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (EncoderException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please use the code tag

Answer (score 5):

I think, you the JAVE (Java Audio Video Encoder) library, so I changed the setCodec **AudioAttributes.DIRECT_STREAM_COPY**

```
public class VideoConvert {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
File source = new File("D:\\video\\mp4\\Sample.ogv");
File target = new File("D:\\video\\ogv\\Sample.mp4");
AudioAttributes audio = new AudioAttributes();
audio.setCodec(AudioAttributes.DIRECT_STREAM_COPY);
audio.setBitRate(new Integer(128000));
audio.setSamplingRate(new Integer(44100));
audio.setChannels(new Integer(2));
VideoAttributes video = new VideoAttributes();
video.setBitRate(new Integer(160000));
video.setFrameRate(new Integer(15));
video.setCodec("mpeg4");
video.setCodec(VideoAttributes.DIRECT_STREAM_COPY);
EncodingAttributes attrs = new EncodingAttributes();
attrs.setFormat("mp4");
attrs.setAudioAttributes(audio);
attrs.setVideoAttributes(video);
Encoder encoder = new Encoder();
try {
    encoder.encode(source, target, attrs);
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (InputFormatException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (EncoderException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}

Comment: I can able to convert from mp4 to ogv format. But I cannot able to convert ogv to mp4 format

Comment: Finally got it working, `VideoAttributes.DIRECT_STREAM_COPY` is the key

Comment: encoder.encode(new MultimediaObject(source), target, attrs);

https://github.com/a-schild/jave2

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what library you're using, but the MPEG-4 container format supports a number of different video and audio codecs.

I see `libfaac` for audio, which lets me assume you're using something ffmpeg-based.

For video you probably want H.264/MPEG-4 AVC, in which case you'll use `libx264` as the video encoder. I've never seen a `mpeg4` video coding format otherwise.

Comment: I'm using **Jave** as library, I use **audio** codec as "setCodec(libfaac)" and for **video** codec use "setCodec(mpeg4)". For encoding I use "setFormat(mpegvideo)" it working fine, but quality of video is poor. What should i do for this issue?